# When is it not possible to choose a specific join algorithm?

Tags: join, hash, nested-loops, mergesort

I've been learning about database joins recently, and I've been wondering, why would I not be able to use a specific join in a specific instance?

For example, I have the following logical plan:

[image]

I know that I can't use one or more the join algorithms SMJ, NLJ, INLJ, BNLJ, Hash Join. I am not sure which one that is, however.

Apart from this example, how can I decide which join algorithms are not suitable for a problem?